# Is it possible to have dynamic routes in pion?

Tags: c++, http, pion-net

I'd like to use *pion 5.0.6* as a small webserver in a VS2017 c++ project. For static routes I can use

```
add_resource("/my/static/route", <handler>)
```

I would need dynamic routes as well - like `"/data/:id/info`
How do I do this?

Comment: This is *not* a tutorial site. Show your code and ask a *specific* question related to it or this is off-topic.

Comment: Ähm, sorry if my question sounded like a simple tutorial request - it is not!
Pion only allows static routes, and if someone who has already worked with that lib has already faced this problem, I would be glad to get a more constructive answer than Jesper's..

Comment: @x y - I didn't provide an *answer*. Merely a *comment*.

Comment: .. which is fine, except if the comment is too hastily. As I said before, the "How do I do this?" might be misleading. I am just trying to find a workaround for the fact, that *pion* is *not* pistache - nor ist it *restbed*. But I *have* to use it. So, if you can help me with another software related  "comment" I would be glad ;)

Answer (score 0):

For those who may need it: I found a solution to *add dynamic routing* to the *pion* webserver. It requires smart router code I found at [hxoht on github](https://github.com/hxoht/route), and works the way that

- all routes - static and dynamic - are set with `httpd->add_resource(<url>, <handler);`
- a 404-handler has to be set with `httpd->set_not_found_handler(<handler>);` and is responsible for dispatching the dynamic routes to the handlers added above.
- your webserver class must derive from `pion::http::server` in order to find the handler by name with `httpd->find_request_handler(<url>, <handler>);`
- in your 404-handler, you use the `Match::test(<dynamic-route>)` method to detect a dynamic route - like in the following code fragment:

  ```
  void handle_404(http::request_ptr& req, tcp::connection_ptr& con)
  {
      Route target;
      Match dynamic = target.set(req->get_resource());
      for (auto& route : dynamic_routes) // Our list of dynamic routes
      {
          if (dynamic.test(route)) // Does the url match the dynamic route pattern?
          {
              request_handler_t h;
              if (find_request_handler(route, h))
              {
                  auto name = get_param_name(route); // e.g. /a/:b -> "b"
                  value = dynamic.get(name); // Save value in string or map<name, value>
                  h(req, con); // Call original handler with value set properly
                  return;
              }
          }
      }
      // If no match then return a 404.
      http::response_writer_ptr w(http::response_writer::create(con, *req,
      boost::bind(&tcp::connection::finish, con)));
      http::response& res = w->get_response();
      res.set_status_code(http::types::RESPONSE_CODE_NOT_FOUND);
      res.set_status_message(http::types::RESPONSE_MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND);
      w->send();
  }
  ```

For using the *pion* webserver in a *multi-threaded* way, I would store the *parsed value* inside the *request* object, which would be derived from `pion::http::request`.

This would work for *Windows* **and** *Linux* :)